# Proper way to upload to s3 in php (uploadify)?

Tags: php, file, upload, amazon-s3, size

I'm currently using the uploadify script and works fine, but I run into an issue of files not being uploaded when it gets around 8mb. I set the php.ini file to 200mb so I don't believe that is the problem. I have a gut feeling it has to do with the way I'm uploading.

**Here is the code:**

```
$response = $s3->create_object("mybucket", 'Folder/SubFolder/'.$FileName, array(
        'fileUpload' => $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'],
        'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_AUTH_READ
    ));
```

Is it not recommended to use `$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']` for the file location?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the code is correct and needs no change. I rechecked the php.ini file and I had upped the **memory_limit = 200M** *but didn't realize there was* **post_max_size = 8M** and **upload_max_filesize = 8M**. So I **changed them to 150M** and now the script works perfectly.